# Regular Expression: Get digit from the ping command output

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

```
a = r'5 packet(s) received'
reg = re.compile(r'(\d*) packet(s) received')
result = re.findall(reg,a)
for i in result:
    print i
```

I am a starter in python. I have to write a script to check the link status. In the output of the "Ping" command, I have to catch the number of received packages in strings eg. `5 packet(s) received`.
My try with `re` is not working. 
Can anyone kindly correct my mistake?

Comment: use \ while writing (s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parenthesis have special meaning in regex. They create groups. To actually match parenthesis, they soud be escaped with `\`.

So, replace this:

```
reg = re.compile(r'(\d*) packet(s) received')
```

with this:

```
reg = re.compile(r'(\d*) packet\(s\) received')
```

Comment: Thank you very much , your answer works! it is just becasue of the "()" in the re.compile() . I only  thought I had used raw string and did not pay much attention on the "()" in regex.